# Getting lat/long coordinates from identified tweets using tweepy; getting KeyError: 'coordinates'

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to get the lat/long coordinates from identified tweets. The part I am having trouble with is the `if decoded['coordinates']!=None: t.write(str(decoded['coordinates']['coordinates'])` block. I don't know exactly if it's working or not because sometimes `~150` tweets will be returned with coordinates as `[None]` before the error is returned, so I believe the error comes back when a tweet with coordinates is found, and then it returns `KeyError: 'coordinates'`.

The following is my code:

```
import tweepy
import json
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import os

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

# This is the listener, resposible for receiving data
class StdOutListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        # Twitter returns data in JSON format - we need to decode it first
        decoded = json.loads(HTMLParser().unescape(data))

        os.chdir('/home/scott/810py/Project')
        t = open('hashtagHipster.txt','a')

        # Also, we convert UTF-8 to ASCII ignoring all bad characters sent by users
        #if decoded['coordinates']:

        # decoded['coordinates'] returns a few objects that are not useful,
        # like type and place which we don't want. ['coordinates'] has a
        # second thing called ['coordinates'] that returns just the lat/long.
        # it may be that the code is correct but location is so few and far
        # between that I haven't been able to capture one. This program just
        # looks for 'hipster' in the tweet. There should be a stream of tweets
        # in the shell and everytime one that has coordinates tehy should be
        # added to the file 'hashtagHipster.txt'. Let me know what you think.

        if decoded['coordinates']!=None:
            t.write(str(decoded['coordinates']['coordinates'])) #gets just [LAT][LONG]
        print '[%s] @%s: %s' % (decoded['coordinates'], decoded['user']['screen_name'], decoded['text'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
        print ''
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):

        print status

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    print "Showing all new tweets for #hipster:"

    # There are different kinds of streams: public stream, user stream, multi-user streams
    # In this example follow #vintage tag
    # For more details refer to https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis
    stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=['hipster'])
```

Any help? thanks.

Comment: `t.write(str(decoded['coordinates']['coordinates']))` looks strange to me. Did you intend to write "coordinates" twice there?

Comment: Yes. decoded['coordinates'] returns a hybrid of json and python that looks something like {'type': "", 'place': "", 'coordinates': [-123.45667], [123.235667]}, and typing decoded['coordinates']['coordinates'] returns just [-123.45667], [123.235667].

Comment: Surely the easiest thing to do would be to print the contents of `decoded['coordinates']` before the `t.print...` line. From the traceback, it looks like it doesn't have a key `coordinates`.

Comment: @SiHa I did that to make sure decoded['coordiantes']['coordinates'] returned what I wanted, and it did. the issue is that it's not be written to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all tweet objects contains the 'coordinates' key, so you have to check that it exists with something like this:

```
 if decoded.get('coordinates',None) is not None:
   coordinates = decoded.get('coordinates','').get('coordinates','')
```

Also, please note that:

> "Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with 'is' or 'is not', never the equality operators."

([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))

Comment: So do you think I could put in that if block and then add a third line that says something like    t.write(coordinates) ?